# Unix time command for OpenMPI jobs

Tags: bash, unix, openmpi

I am trying to use `time` command in Unix to time my [OpenMPI](http://www.open-mpi.org) job.

However, when I submit the job, I receive the output from the job itself but no output from the time command. I have tested using the `date` command in my Bash job that I am submitting and that seems to work fine, so I'm not really sure why my time job does not work. Does anybody know why this might be?

Here is the Bash file that I am using:

```
#!/bin/sh
#PBS -N MPITest
#PBS -l nodes=5,walltime=00:10:00
#PBS -M xxxx@email
#PBS -m abe

module load openmpi-x86_64
time mpirun a.out myname
```

Comment: Does it work when you execute it from the shell ?

Comment: Is /bin/sh really bash? usually `date` is external command and `time` in builtin command. so some shell might not have time command.

Comment: `time` may print to stderr, you should check, does your job management system saves stderr (and where) or not. Or add `2>&1` after the line with `time`

Comment: Try using `/bin/time` rather than `time`, as "time" is often a shell builtin and it may not work in as many situations when compared to the `/bin/time` (or `/usr/bin/time`) binary.

Answer (score 1):

Time outputs to stderr, therefore try checking `youjobname.e123456` file instead of `youjobname.o123456`